# rename files to a different folder with python pathlib

Tags: python, rename, pathlib

This doesn't produce an error and doesn't rename files to 'p1'
Not sure why - Thanks

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
quarter_end = pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.today() -   pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd(startingMonth=3)).date()
QE_Dir = quarter_end.strftime("%m.%d.%Y")
QE = quarter_end.strftime("%Y%m%d")

QE_Dir = '03.31.2021'

AnalyticsDirs = ['/home/javert/Dir1/Dir2/ACG']

for AnalyticsDir in AnalyticsDirs:
    p1 = Path(AnalyticsDir)
    files = [e for e in p1.iterdir() if e.is_file()]
    for file in files:
        thefile = file.name
        thenewfile = re.sub(r'\d{8}', QE, str(thefile))
        p2 = p1.joinpath(QE_Dir)
        p2.mkdir(parents=False, exist_ok=True)
        p3 = p2.joinpath(thenewfile)
        file.rename(p3)
```

Comment: this specific code is invalid and connat run as-is for multiple errors/typos it contains. Equity_AnalyticsDirs is undefined, mkdir() arguments contain invalid character "$" and more.

Comment: Ok, now you can debug it and see what happens.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?&q=how+to+debug+python

Comment: Could you make sure that all paths, in particular the directories that you create, actually exist right before you do the rename? For example, you are calling `p.mkdir()` but `p` has not been defined. Also, print out the full `files` list right before running the rename. My guess is that either the files are not there or there is an error with some of the paths in your code.

Comment: Resolved: didn't understand the need to use Path.name